# Limiting App Engine instances amount

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

While in development I want to keep the costs at a minimum and as a result - limit the amount of App Engine instances to 1 (currently runs on two).

I followed a couple of answers but with no results.

The only official answer I found suggests setting `max_idle_instances` in app.yaml but doing so results in the following error during deployment:

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [400] VM-based automatic scaling should NOT have the following parameter(s): [max_idle_instances]`

Is there any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
manual_scaling:
   instances: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the Standard Environment.

Here's what works for me defining a service using a backend instance -

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

service: worker
instance_class: B1
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1

handlers:
- url: /worker/.*
  script: worker.app
  login: admin
```

As reference, you can see the full project here: https://github.com/alpeware/gcms